# Minimize Graph keeping Connectivity

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm stuck on a graph problem. I'm working with OpenSG and am trying to find paths between two points in a building.

I constructed this graph: [image: graph1]

I use it to find the shortest path between two points in a building:

[image: path in graph]

This is how I find the path:

- I add the start/target node in the graph
- I add edges from start/target node to all nodes that are reachable (this is done with
  IntersectAction in OSG)
- I use the A*-algorithm to find the
  shortest path

I want to minimize the graph now. It doesn't matter if the paths between two points get a little longer i just want to elimate the redundancy that i have now. For example all the light green nodes could be deleted. There is no point in the room that doesnt "see" the door, so there is no need for the nodes. It should look something like this:
[image: minimized graph]

So I have an algorithm that does more or less what I want, but I just thought that this must be a well-known problem. It's not a minimal vertex cover, because for example if in the minimal vertex cover a door-node is not included I won't find a way between the two rooms.

I compared with various Graph-Problems but I couldnt find a real match...

Its very late (6:20am) and I should go to bed and maybe it seems a little bit confusing or maybe its really obvious. Thanks for any kind of input on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the answer myself. If anyone is interested. It is not the normal Vertex Cover but the "Minimum Connected Vertex Cover Problem" (CVCP). There is a nice paper about it:

[Vertex covers and connected vertex covers in 3-connected graphs](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=176537)